Weird behaviors of VBA editor. Closed workbooks remain and more
(1) Workbooks remain in VBA editor after they're closed
This is not a new problem. I've seen many discussions on different platforms; the point is NO solution mentioned can fix the problem for me.
It's not just opening and closing workbooks using VBA somehow leaving them in the VBA editor. Even when I open then close the workbook manually, sometimes (not always) the same thing would happen too.
Set ReadOnlyWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\User\Desktop\AAA.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
Set ReadOnlyWb = Nothing
Workbooks("AAA.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False

Set ReadOnlyWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\User\Desktop\AAA.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
ReadOnlyWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
Set ReadOnlyWb = Nothing

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\User\Desktop\AAA.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True
Workbooks("AAA.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False

These are such simple code, though no matter how I do it, the workbook still remains in the VBA editor.
(2) "Out of memory" alert when opening VBA editor
Not sure if this has anything to do with (1). After I tried so many ways to fix the (1) problem, the "Out of memory" alert started to pop up for those particular excel files.
(3) Worksheets windows in VBA editor cannot be opened
Again not sure if all these problems are related with each other. I can open the windows of modules and ThisWorkbook, but cannot do the same for Worksheets'. Have no idea why.

I've experienced this issue before and ended up uninstalling and reinstalling MS Office. Unfortunately, I don't believe there's a way to fix it using VBA, as the problem lies within the VBA editor itself.

I had the same problem and I did not find a really reliable method to solve it. I was decided to not reinstall Office considering that it must be a solution and only because of that I created an add-in opening and closing a small xlsb file situated in the same folder with the respective add-in. Unfortunately, I played with it in order to help others asking questions (when my testing environment was broken) and it is complicated to test and keep only the necessary part. But it is possible in this way. I cannot swear is the single method, but I did not find something else and abandoned searching

As I wrote in my above comment, I tried creating an add-in able to solve the problem by opening and closing a xlsb small file, situated in the same folder with the respective add-in. To create it please, follow the next steps:
A. Copy the next code in a ThisWorkbook code module of a new workbook:
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents app As Application

Private Sub app_WorkbookBeforeClose(ByVal wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)
   Dim wbExtension As String, arr
   
   If wb.Name = "Close VBProjects.xlsb" Then Set wb = Nothing: Exit Sub
   arr = Split(wb.Name, ".")
   wbExtension = arr(UBound(arr))
   
   On Error GoTo errorHandler
   Select Case wbExtension
    Case "xlsm", "xlsb", "xlam"
      tesRepairVBAProjectStillOpenAFterClosingWorkbooks
   End Select
   
   Exit Sub
errorHandler:
   MsgBox Err.Description & " error occurs in WorkbookBeforeClose event!", vbInformation, "Error"
   If boolCloseVBProjects Then
        Set app = Application
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If boolCloseVBProjects Then
        Set app = Application
    End If
End Sub

Private Function boolCloseVBProjects() As Boolean
  Dim checkBVal As String
  
  checkBVal = GetSetting(myAppG, Sett, boolVal, "No value")
  If checkBVal = "No value" Then
    boolCloseVBProjects = False
  Else
    boolCloseVBProjects = CBool(checkBVal)
  End If
End Function

B. Insert a standard module (good to name it mRibbon, but not mandatory) and copy the next code on it:
Option Explicit

'To memorize the Ribbon object! ___________
#If VBA7 Then
        Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal length As LongPtr)
#Else
        Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
#End If
'_________________________________________

Private chkB As IRibbonControl, boolNo As Boolean
Public myRibbon As IRibbonUI
Const strRib As String = "\MyRibb"

Public Const myApp As String = "RibbApp", mySett As String = "Settings", myVal As String = "Value"
Private cbBox As IRibbonControl

Sub RibbonLoaded_ClearVBE(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Dim Path As String: Path = Environ("temp") & strRib
    Dim File As Integer: File = FreeFile
    Open Path For Output As #File
        Print #File, ObjPtr(ribbon) 'memorize IRibbonUI pointer
    Close #File

   Set myRibbon = ribbon
   'Debug.Print "Ribbon pointer saved..."
End Sub

Sub getRibbon() 'reSet myRibbon if it was lost (it's Nothing):
    Dim Path As String: Path = Environ("temp") & strRib
    Dim File As Integer: File = FreeFile
    Dim ribValue As String
    
    If myRibbon Is Nothing Then
        Open Path For Input As #File
            Input #File, ribValue
        Close #File
        
        #If VBA7 Then
            CopyMemory myRibbon, CLngPtr(ribValue), 8 'place in memory IRibbonUI object from its memorized pointer '64 bit
        #Else
            CopyMemory myRibbon, CLng(ribValue), 4    'place in memory IRibbonUI object from its memorized pointer
        #End If
        Debug.Print "Ribbon object recuperated..."
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub CheckBox_OnAction(ByRef control As IRibbonControl, ByRef pressed As Boolean)
   evaluateCheckBox pressed
   If pressed Then
     Set ThisWorkbook.app = Application 'app with events to trigger app_Workbook_BeforeClose event
   Else
     Set ThisWorkbook.app = Nothing
   End If
End Sub

Sub Chk_StartUp(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef retval) 'change check box when Ribbon is loaded
  Dim checkBVal As String
  checkBVal = GetSetting(myApp, Sett, boolVal, "No value")
  If checkBVal = "No value" Then
    retval = True
  Else
    retval = CBool(checkBVal)
  End If
End Sub

C. Insert another standard module (naming it mApplications, but not mandatory) and copy the next code:
Option Explicit

Public Const myAppG As String = "GostApp", Sett As String = "Settings", boolVal As String = "CheckBValue"

Sub evaluateCheckBox(chkOK As Boolean) 'write the changed check box value in Registry:
  Dim newVal As String: newVal = CStr(chkOK)
  SaveSetting myAppG, Sett, boolVal, newVal
End Sub

Sub tesRepairVBAProjectStillOpenAFterClosingWorkbooks()
  Dim Excel_workbook As Excel.Workbook
  Set Excel_workbook = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Close VBProjects.xlsb")

  Excel_workbook.Close False
  Set Excel_workbook = Nothing
  Debug.Print "VBE cleared..."
End Sub

The above solution creates a new Ribbon Tab (Clear Gosts), with a single group keeping only a check box ("Check it for Action"). Checking it, its value (True) will be written in Registry and used when the add-in is open next time. If you solve somehow the problem, you should uncheck the check box and it will not act, anymore.
To be more reliable, it has a sequence saving the Ribbon pointer in a text file and recuperate it when a VBA error needing to manually close a procedure run appears. After it, most of the time the Ribbon object is lost from memory, it becomes Nothing, but using the above solution it is recuperated and able to be reused.
Now, the XML part:

Save the new workbook as add-in (xlam extension) in a location to be known for the future steps, then close the workbook without saving it. The created add-in is not loaded/open.

Use Office RibbonX Editor (from GitHub) and copy the next xml code in CustomUI14.xml, using Insert menu - Office 2010+ after opening the above saved add-in. I named it ClearVBE, but you can name it as you want:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI onLoad="RibbonLoaded_ClearVBE" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"> 
  <ribbon> 
    <tabs> 
      <tab id="CustomTab" label="Clear Ghosts"  insertAfterMso="TabHome"> 
        <group id="Group1" label="Operational"> 
           <checkBox id="myCheckbox" 
                     label="Check it for Action" 
                     getPressed="Chk_StartUp"
                     onAction="CheckBox_OnAction"/> 
        </group>   
      </tab> 
    </tabs> 
  </ribbon> 
</customUI> 

D. Creating of the xlsb workbook used as helper (to be open - closed) to clear the ghost projects.

Open a new workbook and insert a standard module, where copy the next code:

Option Explicit

Sub testClose()
   '''nothing...
End Sub
Sub CloseMe()
  ThisWorkbook.Close False
End Sub


Save it as "Close VBProjects.xlsb" in the same folder where you saved the add-in. It is mandatory to save it with this name. It will be handled by the add=in...

Now, open the add-in in the next way: Options - Add-ins - Go... using Browse button and go to the folder where you saved it, select and press Open. It will be loaded, a new Ribbon tab (Clear Ghosts) will be created, activate it and tick the Check it for Action check box.
From now on, until you will uncheck the check box it will solve the VBE ghost projects issue.
For a period of 30 days you can download the two workbooks from here. After this period the link will not be valid, anymore. You must count only on the above solution. I hope, well described...
Please, send some feedback after testing it.
